# Titan Time To Live for Vertices

Tags: cassandra, titan, ttl

I'm wanting to build a Titan store on top of Cassandra, and cassandra has a handy TTL option on columns. Is this functionality exposed in Titan? Or does Titan have its own TTL property that can make nodes/edges disappear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no TTL functionality currently in Titan.  An issue has been opened regarding this feature request:

https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/issues/523

Please consider adding your support for and comments on this feature to the issue.

This question comes up on the mailing list with some frequency.  The most recent one can be found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/aureliusgraphs/ttl/aureliusgraphs/BGw6OHmZLTg/OLmgxaYYfaQJ) with an offered best solution for doing this now.  In summary, the idea is to create a timestamp property on vertices (or edges for that matter) then use [Faunus](http://thinkaurelius.github.io/faunus/) to clean up expired graph elements.

Answer (score 2):

Since Titan 0.5.0, Titan does support TTL for vertices, edges, and properties in graphs over Cassandra.  The documentation for the feature can currently be found [here](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.0/advanced-schema.html).  See also the now-closed [github issue](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/issues/523) mentioned by Stephen.